# Copy-constructor inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance, copy-constructor

```
struct A{
  virtual void what() { cout << "Base" << endl; };
};

struct B : A {
  virtual void what() { cout << "Sub" << endl; };
  int m;
  B() : m(10) {};
  B(const A & x) : m(50) {};
};

void main() {
  B b1;
  B b2 = b1;
  cout << "Number:  "
       << b2.m << endl;
};
```

Why isn't b2.m = 50? I'm trying to copy a b-object and i have the copy constructor B(const A & x) : m(50). Do i need need to make a copy c'tor for the derived class ass well ? Like B(const B&x) ??  I thought since a b-object has an a part, we could use B(const A & x) : m(50) instead of the default constructor: :S

In the case where you have a function with the parameter of an A object, you can send in a B object. How come it differs with the copy constructor?

Answer (score 14):

The reason is that `B(const A& x)` is not a copy-ctor — copy constructor for type `T` must always take an lvalue reference to `T` as the first (and have no other non-default arguments) argument. Your class has no defined copy-ctor, so the compiler generates the default one, which does a member-wise copy, hence why `b2.m` is the same as `b1.m`.

> A non-template constructor for class `X` is a copy constructor if its ﬁrst parameter is of type `X&`, `const X&`, `volatile X&` or `const volatile X&`, and either there are no other parameters or else all other parameters have default arguments (8.3.6).

Answer (score 1):

Copy constructors need to be of the same type.

You haven't actually made a copy constructor.  `B(const A & x)` is just a constructor that takes a `const A` by reference.

So, you don't need to make one for the derived class "as well",  but "at all".  As you stated, the type of this will be `B(const B &x)`.

Answer (score 1):

The default copy-ctor for classes of type B would be B(const B&). Since you haven't specified this one, the compiler kindly generates it for you.

Its different with user defined methods as those cannot be compiler generated.